# Remove starting chars from Varchar

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In pl sql i have 
VAR_NUMBER VARCHAR2(30) value is 1122987654.This is prefix + number, so 1122 is prefix and 987654 is number.

I have another table for prefix that is 
PREFIX_TABLE and values are

```
ID->PREFIX
1 -> 1122
2 -> 2233
```

so i need to remove prefix from 1122987654 which matches from above table. In above table we have 1122 so i need to remove 1122 from 1122987654.

Can anyone help ? How to do it in pl sql .

Comment: is the prefix always four digits?

Comment: Christian Palmer: no, it can be 10 digits as well....so not always 4.,,but always smaller than number

Comment: @vc : i seared SUBSTR  but didnt get it how to do it in pl sql

Comment: What happens if prefix_table contains entries for 1122 and 11229 in your example? How can you determine which prefix to use?

Comment: vc 74 : Need to consider longest match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `REGEXP_REPLACE`

This assumes that only single value matches, otherwise use MAX, MIN or put it in a for loop.

```
DECLARE 
    var_number   VARCHAR2(30) := 1122987654; 
    v_prefix_rem VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN 
    SELECT MIN(regexp_replace (var_number, '^' 
                                       ||prefix)) 
    INTO   v_prefix_rem 
    FROM   prefix_table 
    WHERE  var_number LIKE prefix 
                           ||'%'; 
END; 

/
```

**EDIT**

> May match multiple entries but need to consider longest match.

You may use `MIN` for this because the *longest* match will have the *shortest* suffix

```
 select MIN(REGEXP_REPLACE ( VAR_NUMBER, '^'||PREFIX)) INTO VAR_NUMBER 
    FROM 
  PREFIX_TABLE WHERE VAR_NUMBER LIKE  prefix||'%';
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bdf150e17cf57da7566d33b2758a575c)

Comment: May match multiple entries but need to consider longest match

Comment: @VJS : Check now.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a declarative solution but I think the iterative approach might be more readable in this case.

```
DECLARE
   cursor csr is
       SELECT PREFIX
       FROM PREFIX_TABLE
       ORDER BY LENGTH(PREFIX) DESC;

   prefix, number VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    FOR rec in csr
    LOOP
        prefix := SUBSTR(VAR_NUMBER, 1, LENGTH(rec.PREFIX));

        IF (prefix = rec.PREFIX) THEN
        BEGIN
            number := SUBSTR(VAR_NUMBER, LENGTH(rec.PREFIX) + 1);
            EXIT;
        END;
    END LOOP;

    IF (number IS NOT NULL) THEN
        -- prefix and number are available
    END IF;

    ...
END;
```

Should do it

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
Generally Mobile No Start from 7, 8 and 9

declare @string varchar(20)
set @string = '215459924456544'

select substring(@string,patindex('%[7-9]%',@string),10)

Answer (score 0):

The following PL/SQL block ought to do what you need:

```
declare
  cursor mycursor is
    select substr(var_number, length(prefix))
      from varnum, prefix_table
     where var_number like prefix || '%'
     order by length(prefix) desc;

  result  varchar2(30);
begin
  open  mycursor;
  fetch mycursor into result;
  close mycursor
  dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || result);
end;
```

Note that I have not tested this as a cursor, but I did test the query.